# Visual Studio Code: Unit test projects

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, nunit

I know how to setup a separate project in regular Visual Studio: just add another project to the solution, and set the startup project to your asp.net project.

However, in VisualStudio Code, everything is more file and convention based. I am not sure how to include unit testing practices within visual studio code.

**TL;DR:** what is the strategy for seperating your unit tests from your core projects code?

Comment: This documentation should help you _https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-dotnet-test_. Basically what you need to do is creating a new test project and add a reference for the project you want to test in its `.csproj` file.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look!

Comment: So it sounds like I just run `dotnet add reference ../MyApp/MyApp.csproj` in a new, but separate project, which I open in a completely different Visual Studio Code window?

Comment: You don't have to. Create a parent folder for both the test project and the source code. Than you can open that parent folder in Visual Studio Code and you can see both the test code and the source code from the same window.